# Warning message for sencha touch 2 app

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have defined a container called header and using it on every page as header, but I am getting the following warning message.

> "[Ext.Component#constructor] Registering a component with a id
>   (`header`) which has already been used. Please ensure the existing
>   component has been destroyed (`Ext.Component#destroy()`."

Need a help guys. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `id` property, you'll be safe if you use `itemId`

```
Ext.create('Ext.Component',{itemId: 'header'});
```

Otherwise, you'll need to `destroy()` already instantiated component before instantiating a new one with the same id.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you hard-coded `id: 'header'` in `config` of your class definition, so when you initiate it the second time, the warning will be shown.

A better approach is to create that `id` only when you really need through this way:

`Ext.create('your-class-name',{id: your_desired_id})`